# How can I add android widget to ViroCore scene?

Tags: android, virtual-reality, google-vr, 360-panorama, 360-panorama-viewer

I am developing panorama application and I cannot find some ways to implement my Android layouts or Android widgets(TextView, ImageView etc.) to my scene on ViroView.

Is it possible to do in this 3rd party library(ViroCore)?

Thanks, a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you need to inflate the view , then create an `AndoridViewTexture` ,and finally use the function `attachview` and give it the inflated view as a parm.

```
AndroidViewTexture androidTexture = new AndroidViewTexture(viroView.provideView(), pxWidth, pxHeight, isAccelerated);

androidTexture.attachView(inflated);
```